# delete uploaded image in custom module

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

**UPDATE**
I'm updating the question as I solved one of the problem in this question. The original question is below the line.

I'm now able to see the preview of the image as the problem was with the below code

```
$fieldset->addField('banner', 'image', array(
    'label' => Mage::helper('designer')->__('Banner'),
    'required' => false,
    'name' => 'banner',
));
```

where instead of `image`, `file` was written for the type of field. But now the problem is, I'm unable to delete the previous image. I do check the `delete image` checkbox but the file still remains there. Why its not deleting?

---

I'd created a module with **module creator** and able to save images. But when the next time I do want to edit the record it does not show the preview of the uploaded image or the delete checkbox.

[image: screen shot]
Do I need to write additional code in my **adminhtml tab form**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `saveAction` of you controller you need to check if the `delete image` checkbox is checked.

Eg.

```
if (isset($_FILES['checkcsv']['name']) && $_FILES['checkcsv']['name'] != '') {
    try {
        ...
        $uploader->save($path, $logoName);

        save path to database

    } catch (Exception $e) {

    }
}
else if((isset($data['banner']['delete']) && $data['banner']['delete'] == 1)){

    //can also delete file from fs
    unlink(Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . $data['banner']['value']);

    //set path to null and save to database
    $data['banner'] = '';


}
```

Comment: I'd got to this point but the problem was with the code which you had not written in the `else if`

Answer (score 0):

Below code write in your save action of your controller

```
  if (isset($data['image']['delete'])) {
       Mage::helper('your_helper')->deleteImageFile($data['image']['value']);
  }
  $image = Mage::helper('your_helper')->uploadBannerImage();
  if ($image || (isset($data['image']['delete']) && $data['image']['delete'])) {
       $data['image'] = $image;
  } else {
       unset($data['image']);
  }
```

Write below code in your helper

```
    public function deleteImageFile($image) {
    if (!$image) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        $img_path = Mage::getBaseDir('media'). "/" . $image;
        if (!file_exists($img_path)) {
            return;
        }
        unlink($img_path);
    } catch (Exception $exc) {
        echo $exc->getTraceAsString();
    }
}
```

Replace your_helper to your actual helper class